# Quota control in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, quota

How to get quota statistics programmtically in Google App Engine (Java)? Is there any way?

I'd like to be able to get quota statistics, so that my app could email me if the quota is to high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no App Engine API to programmatically access the quota informations.

There was a trusted tester program going on for an upcoming Monitoring API, but as shown on this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/yCXchGOc_fg/0NJDHjQa-uUJ), it is currently on hold.

Comment: Thanks! I keep an eye on that link

Comment: Someone has any news with this issue?