# How Display 'Datastore Read Operations' of an app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a google app engine api to access the usage stats of an app. I want to display the 'Datastore Read Operations' of an app to users so they know how close to the limit they are.

Can this be done on google app engine ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no api to programatically access information on app engine datastore usage statistics including read, write quotas.

There was an [app engine monitoring api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535681/quota-control-in-google-app-engine) project that was being considered to serve this purpose, but it seems to be on hold.

The [feature request for a quota statistics api](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=655) is still open. You can check if this [potamus project](https://github.com/Cloudlock/potamus/) for estimating usage information can be useful for your requirement.